# How to clone an item of a list "li" several times with incremental ids and values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create an automatic pagination bar wich loads its max from a variable called **number**  for example :

**number = 5**

*this is my initial pagination bar :*

```
<ul class="pagination">

  <li class="page" name="1"><a href="#" class="is-active">1</a></li>
  <li class="page" name="2"><a href="#">2</a></li>

</ul>
```

I need to clone the "li" with the name =2 , and create 3 other "li" with incremntal name and content, to obtain finally that form:

```
<li class="page" name="1"><a href="#" class="is-active">1</a></li>
<li class="page" name="2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li class="page" name="3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li class="page" name="4"><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li class="page" name="5"><a href="#">5</a></li>
```

So how can I select the second "li", clone it and create the next "li" with incremntal names and values?

```
createPagination:function (number) {

}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? a <code>for</code> loop should do the trick

Comment: i have selected statically the second item and i have cloned it but i was in need to increment the ids and the value , and tht's exactly my problem

Comment: Concat some strings. '<li class="page" name=" ' + id + ' "><a href="#">' + id + '</a></li>; id++;      Or manipulate the DOM to change their name and their innerHTML after creating them. I'd suggest you the first solution

Comment: Even better, id could be the variable of your for loop. I'm creating the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get last li and then use `for` loop to increment from name(number) of last `li` and create clones. After that you can set name of each clone as current value of counter in loop (also same for text of `a` element in `li`) and append it to `ul`.

```js
var last = $('.pagination li').last();
var num = last.attr('name');

for (var i = num; i <= 5; i++) {
  if (i != num) {
    var clone = last.clone().attr('name', i);
    $(clone).find('a').text(i);
    $('ul').append(clone);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page" name="1"><a href="#" class="is-active">1</a></li>
  <li class="page" name="2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
</ul>
```